# retrieve entity with attribute value found in a different entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

For ex: I have 3 entities Customer, Application, Cases. Customer form needs to get Start date, end date from Case form and calculate the diff between dates.

Case from has Application ID which is also present in Customer form. How can i get the customer entity from Application ID found in Case and update dates from case to customer? I am developing a plugin and should there be a relationship or lookup fields? The similar functionality can be achieved with 'Advanced Find' when a entitiy and its attribute values are given Advance Find fetches all the results.

Any help is greated appreciated!!

Comment: You can create a query with the Advanced Find dialog. When done, you can get the Fetch XML for your query (button in the ribbon) and examine that. A Fetch XML can be converted to QueryExpressions in most cases.

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  Is it correct that you would like to set a field on the customer record based on the difference between two date fields on the Case record?  Is the relationship between these records the following: Case N:1 Application 1:N Customer?  Is this action triggered by a change on either of the case date fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Henk van Boeijen said you could do the following:

```
 private void DoFetchXmlToQueryExpressionConversion()
        {
            // Create a Fetch query that we will convert into a query expression.
            var fetchXml =
                @"<fetch mapping='logical' version='1.0'>
                    <entity name='opportunity'>
                        <attribute name='name' />
                        <filter>
                            <condition attribute='estimatedclosedate' operator='next-x-fiscal-years' value='3' />
                        </filter>
                        <link-entity name='account' from='accountid' to='customerid'>
                            <link-entity name='contact' from='parentcustomerid' to='accountid'>
                                <attribute name='fullname' />
                                <filter>
                                    <condition attribute='address1_city' operator='eq' value='Bellevue' />
                                    <condition attribute='address1_stateorprovince' operator='eq' value='WA' />
                                </filter>
                            </link-entity>
                        </link-entity>
                    </entity>
                </fetch>";

            // Run the query with the FetchXML.
            var fetchExpression = new FetchExpression(fetchXml);
            EntityCollection fetchResult =
                _serviceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(fetchExpression);
            Console.WriteLine("\nOutput for query as FetchXML:");
            DisplayOpportunityQueryResults(fetchResult);

            // Convert the FetchXML into a query expression.
            var conversionRequest = new FetchXmlToQueryExpressionRequest
            {
                FetchXml = fetchXml
            };

            var conversionResponse =
                (FetchXmlToQueryExpressionResponse)_serviceProxy.Execute(conversionRequest);

            // Use the newly converted query expression to make a retrieve multiple
            // request to Microsoft Dynamics CRM.
            QueryExpression queryExpression = conversionResponse.Query;

            EntityCollection result = _serviceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(queryExpression);

            // Display the results.
            Console.WriteLine("\nOutput for query after conversion to QueryExpression:");
            DisplayOpportunityQueryResults(result);

        }
```

That came from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547457.aspx)

You could also do a [Linq Query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334593.aspx) in a similar fashion.

Finding the Relationship name:
Go to System > Customize > Case > view the Relationships (1:N / N:1 / N:N) find the right relationship with your Application click on it, view > Get the 'Name' this is the Schema Name. If your queries have this schema name as its link(join) you should get the right results.